# Numerically-robust methods of calculating $1-(1-x)^n$ for $n >> 1$ and a wide dynamic range of $x$

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

I am trying to calculate $y = 1-(1-x)^n$ for $n$ in the 50-500 range, where $x$ ranges widely between, say, $10^{-20}$ and 1.

The straightforward way is not numerically robust, and loses precision under $y < 10^{-15}$ or so. Example in Python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.logspace(-18,0,19)
>>> x
array([  1.00000000e-18,   1.00000000e-17,   1.00000000e-16,
         1.00000000e-15,   1.00000000e-14,   1.00000000e-13,
         1.00000000e-12,   1.00000000e-11,   1.00000000e-10,
         1.00000000e-09,   1.00000000e-08,   1.00000000e-07,
         1.00000000e-06,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-04,
         1.00000000e-03,   1.00000000e-02,   1.00000000e-01,
         1.00000000e+00])
>>> 1 - (1-x)**20
array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.22044605e-15,
         1.99840144e-14,   1.99840144e-13,   2.00062189e-12,
         1.99995576e-11,   2.00000017e-10,   2.00000017e-09,
         1.99999992e-08,   1.99999982e-07,   1.99999810e-06,
         1.99998100e-05,   1.99981001e-04,   1.99810114e-03,
         1.98111352e-02,   1.82093062e-01,   8.78423345e-01,
         1.00000000e+00])
```

The binomial formula says that I could alternatively calculate $y = nx - \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}x^3 - \ldots - {n\choose k}(-x)^k + \ldots - n(-x)^{n-1} - (-x)^n$.

But that doesn't seem numerically robust (because of the size of $n\choose k$ for large n) unless I cut off the series after an appropriate number of terms that depends on each value I'm trying to compute.

For example, $nx - \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$ is very accurate for $x$ in the $10^{-20}$ to $10^{-10}$ range. But I need more terms the larger $x$ gets.

```
>>> 20*x - 20*19/2*x*x
array([  2.00000000e-17,   2.00000000e-16,   2.00000000e-15,
         2.00000000e-14,   2.00000000e-13,   2.00000000e-12,
         2.00000000e-11,   2.00000000e-10,   2.00000000e-09,
         1.99999998e-08,   1.99999981e-07,   1.99999810e-06,
         1.99998100e-05,   1.99981000e-04,   1.99810000e-03,
         1.98100000e-02,   1.81000000e-01,   1.00000000e-01,
        -1.70000000e+02])
```

Is there a better way to calculate this value, that works not only for large x but for small x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compute it as

```
-expm1(n*log1p(-x))
```

For small $x$, `log1p(-x)` computes the expected $\ln(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$. For small $u$, `expm1(u)` computes $e^u-1=u+O(u^2)$. In combination, you should get the best accuracy for your formula.

```
n=20;
x = np.logspace(-18,-1,18);
-np.expm1(n*np.log1p(-x))
```

which returns with

```
array([  2.00000000e-17,   2.00000000e-16,   2.00000000e-15,
         2.00000000e-14,   2.00000000e-13,   2.00000000e-12,
         2.00000000e-11,   2.00000000e-10,   2.00000000e-09,
         1.99999998e-08,   1.99999981e-07,   1.99999810e-06,
         1.99998100e-05,   1.99981001e-04,   1.99810114e-03,
         1.98111352e-02,   1.82093062e-01,   8.78423345e-01])
```

You will have to switch formulas for $x\ge 1$, as then the logarithm is no longer defined as real function.

Comment: Works like a charm! In my case I goofed on my upper bound, I don't need to worry about $x > 0.5$, so this works great.